# Electric field strength away from a negative spherical charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

I was wonder how would a graph of electrical field strength away from a spherical -ve charge graph would look. Since E= potential gradient I was guessing that since potential increases away from a negative charge , electric field strength would increase away from a negative charge also ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential does increase. This means that the gradient of potential plotted against distance, *r*, from the charge is always positive. But the gradient, $\frac{dV}{dr},$ keeps decreasing in magnitude – just sketch the graph! The field strength in the *r* direction is given by$$E=\ –\frac{dV}{dr},$$so the field is in the –*r* direction and decreases in magnitude the further we go from the negative charge.

Comment: Would it look something like what I uploaded in op ?

Comment: Yes, but as there is radial symmetry, it would be clearer to put the centre of the sphere at $r$ = 0 and to have the $r$ axis in the positive direction only (as it represents the distance from the sphere in any direction). We'd also usually have the graph upside down, reflected about the $r$ axis, the negativity of $E$ showing that the field is directed in the –$r$ direction, that is towards the sphere.

Comment: This is not meant unkindly, but have you consulted an introductory textbook?